# Google App Engine memcache.Client.cas() keeps returning False for missing key

Tags: python, google-app-engine, caching, google-app-engine-python

The following is part of a Python Flask application running on Google App Engine:

```
@app.route('/blabla', methods=['GET'])
def blabla():
    # memcache.add('key', None)  # this "fixes" it!  
    memcache_client = memcache.Client()
    while True:
        value = memcache_client.gets('key')
        if value is None:  # First time
            updated_value = 'Bla'
        else:
            updated_value = value + ', bla'
        if memcache_client.cas('key', updated_value):
            return updated_value
```

Starting with an empty cache, if we make consecutive GET requests to /blabla, I would expect the requests to return:

```
Bla
Bla, bla
Bla, bla, bla
.
.
```

(If for some reason at some point between `.gets()` and `cas()` the cache gets flushed, then I would expect the sequence to restart, no problem.)

But we don’t get anything because `memcache_client.cas()` keeps returning `False` forever, so the program gets stuck in the `while`-loop. Apparently this happens because the key `'key'` does not exist in the beginning.

I know this because if I uncomment the `memcache.add('key', None)`, it sort-of works, because then the key exists and `.cas()` is happy and returns `True`. But if right between the `.add()` and the `.gets()` some other process were to flush the cache, we’d be back to where we started from, with a missing key, and `.cas()` would go back to returning `False` indefinitely. So it is not a good solution.

Why doesn’t `.cas()` work if the key is missing in the beginning? Or at least, why doesn’t `.cas()` accept an `initial_value=` parameter, like its sibling [decr()](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.memcache#google.appengine.api.memcache.Client.decr)? Is it a bug or a feature? I can’t find this documented properly anywhere, except that Guido van Rossum alludes to it in his [single blog post on the matter](http://neopythonic.blogspot.com.mt/2011/08/compare-and-set-in-memcache.html)—reffering to an `assert` he makes that the `.gets()` does not return `None`, he says:

> Aside 2: The assert is kind of naive; in practice you'll have to somehow deal with counter initialization.

Dank je wel Guido—does anyone know how, please?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I figured it out.

```
@app.route('/blabla', methods=['GET'])
def blabla():
    memcache_client = memcache.Client()
    while True:

        if memcache.add('key', 'Bla'):
            # That's all folks!
            return 'Bla'

        # add() failed => the key must already exist, we have to compare-and-set.

        value = memcache_client.gets(key_name)

        if value is None:
            # At the time add() failed the key existed, but now gets() is returning None,
            # so somebody must have deleted the cache entry in between.
            # Let's start from scratch.
            continue

        updated_value = value + ', bla'

        if memcache_client.cas(key_name, updated_value):
            return updated_value
        else:
            continue
```

It’s more complicated than I would have liked it to be, but it works.

The last `else: continue` is redundant but I’m writing it to make it clear that we’re going to continue trying until we succeed.

Although in practice you'll have to somehow deal with giving up after a number of retries.